# Triggers on node creation of certain content-type

Tags: 6, rules

It is a question that always gets answered by "use rules module." Unfortunately, this site depends heavily on a few actions and triggers already, and a migration is not in order.

Are there trigger-addons, tricks or code to make a trigger on creation of a certain node-type only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules and core triggers/actions can co-exist. If it can easily be done in Rules, then why not use both. You then won't have to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to create your own action module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function mymodule_action_info() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_myaction_action' => array(
      'type' => 'node',
      'description' => t('Does something to a node'),
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'hooks' => array(
        // When this action is called.
        'nodeapi' => array('presave', 'insert', 'update', 'view'),
        'comment' => array('insert'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_action().
 */
function mymodule_myaction_action($node, $context) {
  // If the node type is different from FAQ, returns and does nothing.
  if ($node->type == 'faq') {
    // Do something here.
  }
}
```

Comment: The best thing in this way is that, you can call this action function in a hook_nodeapi or hook_node_OP. My favorite technique :)