# Adding content when creating a node

Tags: entities, hooks, nodes

I'm currently building a system to create rapports for a set of possible units. So far I have built a set of content types in CCK that acts like templates where the templates fields are used to add structures that the users creating the rapport will fill out.

I have, in my template, a list of "key value names" that will then be added to the rapport and the user can fill them out.

```
The Template:
a, b, c

The rapport:
* a = x
* b = y
* c = z
```

where x,y,z is entered by the user generating the rapport.

I found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4432/triggers-on-node-creation-of-certain-content-type) here on drupal.stackexchange.com and I guess it's on the right track. But I don't understand what I would fill in 'hooks' with and how to limit the action to only trigger on(/before) node creation. There is also a number of sub-nodes that needs to be created based on the templates, but that part I haven't research yet, if it is connected please include information about it in your answer if possible.

Comment: For hooks you might want to use 'nodeapi' => array('presave') to trigger it before the node is saved. Alternatively, if you want to use rules for this I can show you how a custom rules event and action can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [question you linked to](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4432/triggers-on-node-creation-of-certain-content-type), the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) will do this very well and can be used to call your custom actions when criteria are met during pre-save, validation, or other stages you might need.

It's worth pointing out that, since you want custom nodes created, you're likely to already need to be writing custom code. In this case a better approach might be to write an implementation of [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) (Drupal 6) or [hook_node_{operation}()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/) (Drupal 7) that means you can fire your own custom code at specific points during node creation.

Take a look at this [question about how to make nodes programatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12836/create-a-content-node-from-another-content), and also [this article with more detail about the process in Drupal 7](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://timonweb.com/how-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-drupal-7) (only in Google cache). Extract of the article:

> **1 Initialize a node object**
>
> ```
>  $node = new stdClass(); // We create a new node object $node->type =
>  "page"; // Or any other content type you want $node->title = "Your
>  title goes jere"; $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or any language
>  code if Locale module is enabled. More on this below * $node->path =
>  array('alias' => 'your node path'); // Setting a node path
>  node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values. $node->uid =
>  1; // Or any id you wish
> ```
>
> *We set LANGUAGE_NONE for $node->language, if you don’t have the locale module enabled, the node will not be assigned any particular
>   language. So that's why we put here the constant LANGUAGE_NONE. In
>   Drupal, nodes and fields can exist in more that one language, so if
>   your site is multilingual you should specify the language code for
>   your field. You can configure languages and get language codes by
>   going this path in Drupal administration: Configuration -> Regional
>   and language -> Languages.
>
> **2 Add a body field**
>
> ```
> // Let's add standard body field
> $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'This is a body text';
> $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = 'Here goes a summary';
> $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html'; // If
> field has a format, you need to define it. Here we define a default
> filtered_html format for a body field
> ```
>
> **3 Add custom fields**
>
> ```
> // Let's add some CCK/Fields API field. This is pretty similar to the
> body example  $node->field_custom_name[$node->language][0]['value'] =
> 'This is a custom field value'; // If your custom field has a format,
> don't forget to define it here
> $node->field_custom_name[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'This is a
> custom field value'; // And etc. you can add as much fields here as
> your content type has. The sky is the limit... and the server specs,
> of course ;)
> ```
>
> **4 Add file / image fields**
>
> ```
> // Some file on our system $file_path =
> drupal_realpath('somefile.png'); // Create a File object $file =
> (object) array(   'uid' => 1,   'uri' => $file_path,   'filemime' =>
> file_get_mimetype($file_path),   'status' => 1, );  $file =
> file_copy($file, 'public://'); // Save the file to the root of the
> files directory. You can specify a subdirectory, for example,
> 'public://images'  $node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] =
> (array)$file; //associate the file object with the image field:
> ```
>
> **5 Add a term to a node**
>
> ```
> $node->field_tags[$node->language][]['tid'] = 1;
> ```
>
> field_tags here is the name of a term reference field attached to your
>   content type, 1 is a term id you wish to assign to a node. Simple!
>
> **6 Save a node**
>
> ```
> $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
> node_save($node); // After this call we'll get a nid
> ```