# Create a content node from another content

Tags: nodes, 6, rules

I'm wondering how to create a content from another content. I'll give an example, it will be easier to understand :

We have a content-type "Planning" which has three fields : 2 user references and one date, which can be multiple filled (let's say the dates are appointments). So in result, a planning will link 2 users and this node will display all the dates these 2 are supposed to meet.

Also, we have another content-type "Appointment".

I'd like that after the creation of the Planning, the appointments get automatically created, always linking the 2users.

First, I've looked into the module Flexi-Field but it doesn't create the node. Then I thought about Rules but I don't know how to create the multiple nodes Appointments due to the multiple date fields.

I know I could do it with Rules through a PHP custom code, but if there's any easier solution, I'd like to hear about them :-)

Thanks for any suggestion !

Cheers all !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both your content types are defined for Plannning and Appointment already, you can easily create appoint nodes on-the-fly when a Planning node is saved.

You want to look at the following 2 references:

- [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)
- [Programmatically create nodes](http://www.group42.ca/creating_and_updating_nodes_programmatically_in_drupal_7)

It would look something like this (NOT TESTED):

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'planning') {
    foreach (element_children($node->field_appointment_dates) as $a_single_appointment_date) {
      $appt_node = new stdClass();
      $appt_node->type = 'appointment';
      node_object_prepare($appt_node);
      $appt_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or your language type ...
      $appt_node->title = 'Some new appointment';
      $appt_node->field_appointment_date = $a_single_appointment_date[0]['value'];
      node_save($appt_node);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is for Drupal 7. While the idea is the same, I'm sure the OP would appreciate an example in 6 as well.

Comment: Hi sorry. new here :P You're right I didn't notice it was D6. I've actually only done this in D6. You still use (the D6 equivalent) hook_node() on $op==insert, and you basically create the node the extact same way ... :/

Comment: Thank you tenken, thanks to you, i've found a way to do it ! It's a bit different from yours : the solution is in the other answer

Answer (score 1):

```
function planning_nodeapi(&$node, $op) {
    if ($node->type == 'planning' && $op=='insert') {
    $txt = $node->field_plan_texte[0]['value']; // some text
    $user = $node->field_plan_user[0]['uid']; //user reference
    $date = $node->field_plan_dates[0]['value']; // date of appointments, even if multiples
    for ($i=0;$i<count($node->field_dates);$i++){
       $appt = new StdClass();
       $appt->type = 'appointment';
       $appt->uid = 1;
       $appt->title = "pd";
       $appt->field_appt_txt[0]['value']=$txt;
       $appt->field_appt_user[0]['uid'] = $user;
       $appt->field_appt_date[0]['value'] = $node->field_dates[$i]['value'];
       node_save($appt);
    }   
  }
}
```

This is valid for D6 ;-)
Thanks @ tenken !